# How to find system.Type of parameter of MethodDeclaractionSyntax with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I get IL of methods with extension method:

```
public static byte[] getIL(this Type t,string nameOfMethod)
{
    MethodBody mb=t.GetMethods(BindingFalgs...).Where(m=>m.Name ==nameOfMethod ).Single();
    return mb.GetMethodBody().GetIlAsByteArray();
}
```

Because my solution has Overload (with same name) method I got exception(has  more than one).

So I need to use below method that need Type[].

```
//this will replace in above method
m.GetMethod("NameOfMethod",ArrayTypeOfParameter);
```

But how can I get Type from TypeSyntax ?

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclarationSyntax(MethodDeclarationSyntax m)
 {
 foreach(ParameterSyntax p in m.ParameterList.Parameters)
   {
       TypeSyntax t=p.Type;
      //how get system.Type here
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need *symbols* here.

From your `ParameterSyntax` p, use `SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol` to get the `IParameterSymbol`, and then look at its `Type` to get the `ITypeSymbol` you are interested in.

Comment: I need system.Type to send for getMethod .how get system.type from ITypeSymbol?

Comment: You can't -- reflection and roslyn are separate worlds. You could find a workaround using Type.MetadataName though and use that to find the correct type via reflection.